# Microsoft Active Directory Port

Tags: active-directory, port, firewall, ports

What ports do you need to open in a firewall to connect a remote Windows computer to a Microsoft Active Directory server domain behind that firewall?

Comment: Programming angle? I won't close it but others will.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Did not think of it back then. Let me close it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using a VPN for this rather than opening your firewal. Looking into setting up a firewall with Routing and Remote Access or with a dedicated VPN hardware solution.

Answer (score 9):

1. TCP 135 : MS-RPC
2. TCP 1025 & 1026 : AD Login & replication
3. TCP 389 : LDAP
4. TCP & UDP 53 : DNS
5. TCP 445 : SMB , Microsoft-ds
6. TCP 139 : SMB
7. UDP 137 & 138 : NetBIOS related
8. UDP 88 : Kerberos v5

See: http://msmvps.com/blogs/rexiology/archive/2006/04/05/89389.aspx